# Nested Molecule of atomic design

Tags: atomic

Today I have learning about Atomic Design but I'm get stuck about the molecule nesting,
I'm just see source code downloading from Github and I see they nesting molecule inside molecule

So I want to know does molecules can nested?
I mean molecule inside molecule
thanks

Comment: Does the source code you download is public? You should share the link if it's not private. Atomic Design can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: Ok here is the repo https://github.com/diegohaz/arc

Comment: IconButton molecule: https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/blob/master/src-example/components/molecules/Modal/index.js

Modal molecule: https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/blob/master/src-example/components/molecules/IconButton/index.js

the modal molcule is included IconButton which is IconButton is molecule also

Comment: so that is true way or no?

Comment: I know Atomic Design is like this:

Atoms->Molecules->Organisms

Comment: For me personally, atoms should be both platforms, build-systems, and workflow agnostics. Or at least framework agnostics if you limit it to a web browser. So the best place to declare atoms is in the CSS.

Comment: Ideally, molecules and organisms should be platforms agnostics too but seems that's impossible in the current state. (currently no universal intermediate format standard for this). [Mitosis](https://github.com/builderio/mitosis) (formerly JSX-Lite) is closest one but it only for web platform.